# Quotation marks only appear after entering them twice - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have a problem with my IntelliJ IDEA.
When I press `"` nothing happens, unless I start typing, then the text I type appear inside the quotation marks, like so: `"foobar"`. But, when I start the text with a "U" or "u" letter, then it enters `Ü` or `ü` respectively. I didn't experiment with all letters, I assume it's a problem with language setting in the IDE. It's in English, but maybe the keyboard settings have changed?

The problem appears only in one window of IDE - not in any other window and not outside of the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after posting the question I just reopened both windows. Upon reopening, the problem stopped existing. I'm not sure why it used to happen, but it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 13):

The issue is caused by keyboard layout, not the IntelliJ Idea. Check if you have US International keyboard layout set. If so, change it to the regular English US. This resolved my issue.

Comment: That is not the issue at all. This is definitely the issue with Intellij as it does not behave same even in text editors or while typing here...

Comment: Well your observation does make sense, but is not correct I'm afraid. I did some googling just out of curiosity, and it actually is the US international keyboard's fault (actually it's by design). It has some special characters like apostrophe, quote and some others that do nothing by themselves, but they wait for other keystroke to take effect. For example you press ' and then e and the result is é. Because it's meant for languages with accents. So it seems IntelliJ editor just follows the specs while some other editors do not.

Comment: Bladito, you are perfectly right. Thanks - I have fixed it by replacing with plain US keyset,  I wonder why my keyboard was set to US international...
P. S. Unfortunately I replied in the wrong place and did not read the post attentively...